# Remove locked questions from hot questions

Tags: feature-request, support, hot-questions, locked-questions

There's a question over on AskUbuntu... you know the one.  Its a hot question. It also happens to be mod locked (not closed).

This means no new answers, no new comments, and no new votes.

Because of the excessive immaturity of users commenting on the question over there (and given the comments I saw that are likely deleted - from over *here* rather than there) and the... lets just say "provocatively phrased title" (which isn't at issue here - I have opinions about it though if you want to read about that elsewhere) it is locked.  And that is the issue - it is locked.  There is no interaction that anyone can have with the post from HNQ.

So remove it from the HNQ pool.  There is no reason for a locked post to *ever* be in HNQ because of the lack of interaction that people can have with it. Protection says "no newbies".  A locked post says "everyone, just go away."  Please let that message apply to the HNQ pool.

And please, it is the very last thing I want showing up in a other community advertised post in a big box for my manager to see on the side of my browser.

Comment: Hasn’t Unix always been famous for its explicit command names? Rewriting the question title might well have been the better option; “Can’t find foo” wasn’t that useful anyway.

Comment: If it bothers so many people, editing the problematic parts is the best way, but can't really tell - guess if the whole community couldn't come with something better, maybe there isn't. Anyway, preventing locked question from appearing in the HNQ sounds trivial, surprised it's not the case yet.

Comment: But it's ***locked*** - it can't be edited.

Comment: @MichaelT: I meant “the better option” over locking. Before it got locked, anyone could have edited it; then at the time of locking, the moderator could have edited it instead of locking.

Comment: It's been edited.

Comment: @Deer, yeah, wonder what took the moderator two whole days though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - they were looking for the aforementioned component, looking hard.